# /bin/ls is ALWAYS showing hidden files. it should not

Tags: command-line

No matter how i try to make sure /bin/ls has not been aliased, executing any ls command always shows the hidden files. How can I change this?

As the # prompt shows this is being run as root.

```
# type ls
ls is /bin/ls
# ls ~
.CFUserTextEncoding
.mysql_history
Downloads
.bash_history
...
```

Comment: When the `root` user runs `ls` all files are shown. Are you logged in as `root`?

Comment: @fd0 Wow, I just learned something new https://superuser.com/questions/931554/on-os-x-why-does-sudo-ls-show-hidden-dot-files

Comment: @nohillside  Glad to share ;-)

Comment: @fd0 Please post an answer

Answer (score 3):

fd0 is correct.  I was running as root.  Though I have to say that I'm completely baffled as to why this should be the case.  Well, whatever, nobody cares about my bafflement.  Sorry for the wasted bandwidth.

i can't figure out how to give fd0 credit.

Comment: No need for points, I just up voted  your answer, mark it as solved.